# MPI_Waitsome is Failing

Tags: c, mpi, nonblocking

I am attempting to use the MPI_Waitsome function but with a different array of indices (and outcount) dependent on the processor rank. All 16 processors return the same error:

```
[0] fatal error
Fatal error in MPI_Waitsome: Invalid MPI_Request, errror stack:
MPI_Waitsome(count=13, req_array="some address", out_count="some address", indices="some address", status_array="some address") failed
Invalid MPI_Request
```

The piece of code in question is as follows:

```
#include <mpi.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int row(int inrank);
int column(int inrank);

int main()
{
    int numtasks, rank, len, rc, i, n, tag = 1, outbufp, inbuf1[3], inbuf2[4];

    MPI_Status stats[13];
    MPI_Request reqs[13];

    for (i = 0; i<3; i++) {
        inbuf1[i] = MPI_PROC_NULL;
    }

    for (i = 0; i<4; i++) {
        inbuf2[i] = MPI_PROC_NULL;
    }

    char hostname[MPI_MAX_PROCESSOR_NAME];

    MPI_Init(NULL,NULL);

    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &numtasks);

    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);

    MPI_Get_processor_name(hostname, &len);

    printf("Number of tasks= %d My rank= %d Running on %s\n",numtasks,rank,hostname);

    outbufp = rank;

    n = 0;

    for(i = (row(rank) * 4); i < ((row(rank) + 1) * 4); i++){       
        if(i != rank){          
            MPI_Isend(&outbufp, 1, MPI_INT, i, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &reqs[n]);
            n++;
        }       
    }

    for(i = row(rank); i < 16; i += 4){
        if(row(i) != row(rank)){        
            MPI_Isend(&outbufp, 1, MPI_INT, i, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &reqs[n]);
            n++;
        }       
    }

    for(i = (row(rank) * 4); i < ((row(rank) + 1) * 4); i++){   
        if(i != rank){          
            MPI_Irecv(&inbuf1, 1, MPI_INT, i, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &reqs[n]);
            n++;
        }       
    }
    if(row(rank != column(rank))){
        for(i = (column(rank)*4); i < ((column(rank) + 1)*4); i++){         
                MPI_Irecv(&inbuf2, 1, MPI_INT, i, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &reqs[n]);
                n++;        
        }
    }

    int *indic;
    indic = (int*) malloc(100*sizeof(int));

    for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
        indic[i] = i;
    }
    MPI_Waitsome(13, reqs, n, indic, stats);

    printf("inbuf(y) =\t");

    for(i=0;i<3;i++){
        printf("%d\t",inbuf1[i]);
    }
    if(row(rank) != column(rank)){
        for(i=0;i<4;i++){
            printf("%d\t",inbuf2[i]);
        }
    }
    MPI_Finalize();

    return 0;
}

int row(int inrank){
    return (inrank - inrank%4)/4;
}
int column(int inrank){
    return (inrank%4);
}
```

My aim is to transfer data between processors in a Cartesian grid, I am aware of the new Cartesian virtual topology however, I wish to first hard code a version. I am considering using 2 MPI_Waitall functions within if statements, however I can not see why the MPI_Waitsome function is currently not working. I would guess that it may have something to do with the fact that the array of indices is dynamic, however, this must be so since it is of a differing size depending on whether the processor is on or off diagonal.

EDIT: Solved using two MPI_Waitall functions as below

```
if(row(rank) != column(rank)){
    for(i = (column(rank)*4); i < ((column(rank) + 1)*4); i++){         
            MPI_Irecv(&inbuf2[m], 1, MPI_INT, i, rank, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &reqs2[m]);
            m++;        
    }
}

//printf("Proc %d\n", rank);

MPI_Waitall(9, reqs, stats);

if(row(rank)!=column(rank)){
    MPI_Waitall(4, reqs2, stats2);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First thing first. **Listen to your compiler warnings**. It will tell you something like:

```
mpiwaitsome.c: In function ‘main’:
mpiwaitsome.c:83:28: warning: passing argument 3 of ‘MPI_Waitsome’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
     MPI_Waitsome(13, reqs, n, indic, stats);
                            ^
In file included from mpiwaitsome.c:1:0:
/usr/include/mpi.h:1817:20: note: expected ‘int *’ but argument is of type ‘int’
 OMPI_DECLSPEC  int MPI_Waitsome(int incount, MPI_Request array_of_requests[],
                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~
```

It shows how important it is to always fix your warnings. The compiler tells you very clearly that you are using the API wrong. You can then check out the documentation:

```
outcount
    number of completed requests (integer) 
array_of_indices
    array of indices of operations that completed (array of integers) 
array_of_statuses
    array of status objects for operations that completed (array of Status).
```

Are all **output parameters**. You use it like this.

```
int *indic = malloc(n*sizeof(int));
int outcount;
MPI_Waitsome(n, reqs, &outcount, indic, stats);
```

I am not sure what you thought to tell MPI by setting the indices like this. You need the indices determine which operation actually completed. *Some* means that not all may be completed. You must not read the receive buffers unless you know the respective operation has completed. If you want to read all receive buffers and reuse the send buffers, then use `MPI_Waitall`.

Apropros buffers, you are providing the same pointer `&inbuf1` / `&inbuf2` for each of the iterations of those loops. Writing to the same location via multiple concurrent receive operations wrong. Also be very careful - if `inbuf` wasn't a `int[]`, but a `int*`, then `&inbuf` would be the address of the pointer... You probably want something:

```
MPI_Irecv(&inbuf1[magical-formula-for-index], 1, ...
```

Comment: Thanks for this, my issue is that at this time I'm compiling on the visual studio developer command line, so only get error message when I compile rather than errors and warnings, although maybe there is a flag for this? I'm currently trying to rig something up with Cygwin. Having corrected my waitsome parameters, I no longer get error message but the same as another version of my program in which I have set up to waitall functions, one within an if statement, whereby the program never prints anything, it just waits :(

Comment: Please provide a version that hangs while you think it should work as an edit to the question or a new question. I'm afraid I can't help you with your particular IDE, but there must be a reasonable way to get warnings.